# How to add another countrie to Google map api autocomplete script

Tags: api, dictionary, autocomplete, countries

I have a trouble trying to figure out how to add another country to Google autocomplete API script, right now works fib for Australia but I want to add UK and India as well.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&country:au&callback=initAutocomplete&key=AIzaSyC7o6A3FQy0AmK20Ct65Pvqqvsk2UxbacY" async defer></script>-->
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&country:au&key=<?php echo GOOGLE_APP_ID;?>"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **country:au** from your script and it will search for all countries.

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&country:au&callback=initAutocomplete&key=AIzaSyC7o6A3FQy0AmK20Ct65Pvqqvsk2UxbacY" async defer></script>-->

Comment: Remove &country:au from this script url. 

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&country:au&callback=initAutocomplete&key=AIzaSyC7o6A3FQy0AmK20Ct65Pvqqvsk2UxbacY%22

Comment: thanks guys still pointing info to Australia only must have another script somewhere else as well.